# I need help making CSS for a modern vertical navbar

Tags: css, navigation, nav

I have been playing around with a (I think) pretty modern vertical nav bar, I've gotten it pretty much down, however its like not really responsive, like at all. And its better off if its rewritten. Any help is appreciated :), or if you have any video that you know of or found that'll gear me in the direction that'll work too!

I've tried making a two normal sections one section thats about 8vw wide and goes all the way down and then having a second section thats, well, for the rest of my content.

Hope you guys are being safe.

[What I designed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGRbk.png)

As for code, I've made a webflow of pretty much of what I had, I don't have my main PC on me at the moment since I'm moving houses, hopefully this gives a bit of an in-site of what I had.

https://looskie.webflow.io

Comment: Code of html and css will help to look into

Comment: @Manjuboyz I've added a webflow of pretty much of what I had, I dont quite have my PC on hand at the moment since I'm moving houses. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Oh ok, it will really good if you have code, I just posted answer, hope it helps to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Oswald, sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #fff
}

a {
  text-decoration: none
}

li {
  list-style: none
}

ul {
  margin: 0
}

.main-nav {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 45px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #4c4c4c;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
}

ul.nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.nav li {
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 45px;
}

ul.nav li a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">METHODOLGY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats perfect Manjuboyz! Thank you so much, you're amazing exactly what I'm looking for. I hope you're being safe!